# Programmatically create DB2 Receive port

Tags: db2, adapter, biztalk

I am working on creating BizTalk receive location programmatically 
I know that we can create Receive port and locations programmatically for file and WCF adapters. In similar way when I try to create DB2 adapter port & Location getting created but the configuration properties are not getting applied.

Following is the customprop xml I am using

```
<CustomProps>
    <AdapterConfig vt = "8">
        <Receive xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <connectionString>ABC</connectionString>
            <sqlCommand>xyz</sqlCommand>
            <documentRootElementName>DB2Records</documentRootElementName>
            <documentTargetNamespace>http://db2.com</documentTargetNamespace>
            <batchSize>-1</batchSize>
            <CommandTimeout>30</CommandTimeout>
            <pollingUnitOfMeasure>Seconds</pollingUnitOfMeasure>
            <pollingInterval>30</pollingInterval>
            <uri>test</uri>
            <columnMapping>Attributes</columnMapping>
        </Receive>
    </AdapterConfig>
</CustomProps>
```

Can anyone help me understand if we can create DB2 receive location from C# code?

Comment: Any reason why you would try to create it from C# instead of via a binding file? There are tools like BTSTask.exe which can import a binding file in itself as well.

Comment: It was customer requirement to create ports based on events in the website. I am able to archive this now. the customprops xml was wrong once i used right one it solved my issue